# How to get randomly a pair elements from a 2d Array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have the following Array :

```
arr= new int[][] { { 20, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 1, 0 } };
```

I want getting randomly one lement from `arr`.
For example : `[3,2]` or `[20,0]`

I'm using the following code :

```
Random r=new Random();        
    int rd= rand.nextInt(arr.length);
```

Comment: `int[] randomArrayPair = arr[randomNumber];`?

Comment: `int[] randomPair = arr[randomNumber];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `int[] randomPair = arr[randomNumber];`.
If you want to get that numbers in seperated variables, you can add `int num1 = randomPair[0];int num2 = randomPair[1];`